# Script to keep specific directories that contains a .txt file and deletes the files from the other directories without the specific .txt file

Tags: linux, bash, script

I am almost done with the script but this outputs directories. What I would like is to have an output of files. Anyway one of you guys wanna help me out? :)

```
    #!bin/bash
( find /testftp/* -type d ;
  find /testftp/* -type f -iname DONOTDELETE.TXT -printf '%h'
) | sort | uniq -u
```

Output is:

```
/testftp/logs
```

The output is the directory of where DONOTDELETE.TXT doesn't exist. It's pretty close. Just need to display the files.

Comment: **(1)** You want to delete **files only** in a directory that does not have DONOTDELETE.TXT, but not the directory itself? **(2)** Which directory set does the printf display now? The ones with the TXT file or the ones without it?

Comment: (1) Yes! (2) printf displays the directory where the DONOTDELETE.TXT DOESN'T exist. BUT it also displays "/testftp" which is the directory containing the other subdirectories. So its pretty close but I'm lose now LOL

Comment: Try `-exec list {}/*` instead of `-printf '%h'`. If it shows the correct files **only**, maybe you can try `-exec rm -f {}/*` (**Caution: This is dangerous!**). [_Also, this maybe useful._](http://www.linux.ie/newusers/beginners-linux-guide/find.php)

Comment: With this code `( find /testftp -type d ;   find /testftp -type f -iname DONOTDELETE.TXT -exec list {} \; ) | sort | uniq -u ` Output is : ` find: list: No such file or directory
/testftp
/testftp/logger
/testftp/logs ` DONOTDELETE.TXT is under ` /testftp/logger `

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `ls` not `list` (always forget it!)

Comment: Yeah hehe...updated my code under the question. Any feedbacks? :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2603/discussion-between-adtc-and-joyian-yee-hernandez)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take on it:

```
#! /bin/bash

SPECIAL_FILE=DONOTDELETE
LOGFILE=clean.$(date +"%Y-%d-%m.%H%M%S").log   
FIND_BASE="$1"
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
        echo "Syntax $(basename $0) <FIND_BASE>"
        exit 1
fi
if [ "$FIND_BASE" = "." ]; then
        FIND_BASE=$(pwd)
else
        FIND_BASE=$(pwd)/$FIND_BASE
fi

for d in $(find $FIND_BASE -type d -print); do
        if [ "$d" != "$FIND_BASE" ]; then
                ls $d | grep $SPECIAL_FILE &> /dev/null
                if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
                        echo "Deleting $d" | tee -a $LOGFILE
                        rm -rf $d 2>/dev/null
                else
                        echo "Ignoring $d, contains $SPECIAL_FILE" | tee -a $LOGFILE
                fi
        fi
done
exit 0
```

Add this to a script, modify the variables with your own naming convention if you like (for the special file and the log name), and then just call it with the starting directory path as a parameter. It will exclude any directory containing the file you want, and delete all the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Thought i'd give this one a go.

```
#!/bin/bash
# file name and path can not have spaces for this to work.

ignorefile=DONOTDELETE.TXT
dir="`find /testftp/* -type d`";
exists=$(ls $dir | for each in $(find $dir -type f -iname $ignorefile -printf '%h\n'); do echo -en "grep -v $each |" ; done | sed '$s/.$//') 
direxists=$(ls $dir | eval $exists | grep -v $ignorefile | sed 's/:/\//g' | sort | uniq -u)

for pth in $direxists; 
do 
if [ -d $pth ]; then 
if [ "$(ls -A $pth)" ]; then 
echo rm -f ""$pth*""
fi
fi
done
```

```
reproduce:
changed dir="`find /testftp/* -type d`";
to
dir="`find ./testftp/* -type d`";

mkdir testftp && cd testftp
for x in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do mkdir $x; done
for y in 1 2 3 4 6 7 9; do touch $y/blah; done
touch 5/DONOTDELETE.TXT
touch 5/some.log
touch 8/DONOTDELETE.TXT
touch 8/another.file

cd ..
$ ./script.sh 
rm -f ./testftp/1/blah
rm -f ./testftp/2/blah
rm -f ./testftp/3/blah
rm -f ./testftp/4/blah
rm -f ./testftp/6/blah
rm -f ./testftp/7/blah
rm -f ./testftp/9/blah
```

Comment: I tried this. ` #!/bin/bash
# file name and path can not have spaces for this to work.

ignorefile=DONOTDELETE.TXT
dir="`find ./testftp/* -type d`";
exists=$(ls $dir | for each in $(find $dir -type f -iname $ignorefile -printf '%h\n'); do echo -en "grep -v $each |" ; done | sed '$s/.$//')
direxists=$(ls $dir | eval $exists | grep -v $ignorefile | sed 's/:/\//g' | sort | uniq -u)

for pth in $direxists;
do
if [ -d $pth ]; then
if [ "$(ls -A $pth)" ]; then
echo rm -f ""$pth*""
fi
fi
done ` But it didn't do anything :(

Comment: any thoughts? :)

Comment: what you pasted back in here and what i put up there are 2 different things. and if your using cygwin/windows forget it

Answer (score 0):

If you have bash 4+ (check with `bash --version`), you can do this in a two-liner:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in ./**/; do [[ -f "$f"/DONOTDELETE.TXT ]] || rm -f "$f"/*; done
```

Note that `shopt -s globstar` needs to be on its own line - don't just prepend it to the for loop with a `;`.

`./**/` expands to every subdirectory in the current directory, and their subdirectories recursively. If you only want to go down the tree a single level, use `./*/` instead (and don't bother setting globstar); if you want finer control than that, you'll have to mess around with `find` instead (specifically the `-maxdepth` and `-mindepth` options). I use `./**/` instead of `**/` in case any of your directories begin with a `-`: this stops them from being seen as

`[[ -f "$f"/DONOTDELETE.TXT ]]` tests to see if that file exists and is a file (if you want it to work even if DONOTDELETE.TXT may be something other than a file, use `-e` instead of `-f`). Strictly speaking, you don't need the `/` in there, since $f contains a trailing slash, but I think it looks better this way, and in general redundant forward-slashes are harmless. `||` means OR - if (and only if) that test evaluates to *false*, then the code to the right of it will be executed, in this case `rm -f "$f"/*` - which deletes every file, except the hidden ones.

If you want to delete hidden files too, you can use something like:

```
for f in ./**/; do [[ -f "$f"/DONOTDELETE.TXT ]] || rm -f "$f"/* "$f"/.*; done
```